# Java back end: Guarantee two Facebook users are friends

Tags: java, facebook

I want to be able to get a user's friends and then store them inside of my database. The issue is with javascript sdk the friends would be sent to the client and then the client would send me the list of friends.This data can obviously be manipulated now so how do I guarantee these two people are really Facebook friends? I know of the php sdk, but I am using complete java for back-end and we have no plans to ever use php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call Facebook API from your Java back-end server.

There are few libraries you can use:

http://facebook4j.org/en/index.html

or

http://restfb.com/